# websphere in cluster - how to know which node the request was served by?

Tags: java, websphere

We are trying to configure a websphere cluster of 8 nodes and deploy an app. Is there any way to identify which server the request was processed by without looking at the application logs. In tomcat, if jvmroute in set, based on the value of JSESSIONID from http trace, the server can be identified. Need something similar for websphere application server. Using was8.5 and apache 2.2.3 worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSESSIONID has a clone ID in it, that clone ID identified a backend cluster member. An alternative is to log %{WAS}e in your webserver access log -- it will contain the backend hostname and port.